# What is the proper razor syntax for this Url.Action code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, syntax, razor

Given the following code, what is the proper Razor syntax??

```
    $('#ShowClosed').click(function () {
        var urlString = '@Url.Action("GetWorkOrders", "WorkOrders")?ShowClosed=$("#ShowClosed").valueOf';
        alert(urlString);
        $("#jqgWorkOrdersList").jqGrid().setGridParam({ url: urlString }).trigger("reloadGrid");
    });
```

The alert is returning /website/MyController/MyAction?ShowClosed=$("#ShowClosed").valueOf

Edit:  This is the correct code.

```
    $('#ShowClosed').click(function () {
        var urlString = '@Url.Action("GetWorkOrders", "WorkOrders")?ShowClosed=' + $("#ShowClosed").attr("checked");
        $("#jqgWorkOrdersList").jqGrid().setGridParam({ url: urlString }).trigger("reloadGrid");
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You included javascript code in the string..

```
$('#ShowClosed').click(function () {
    var urlString = '@Url.Action("GetWorkOrders", "WorkOrders")?ShowClosed=' + $("#ShowClosed").is(":checked");
    alert(urlString);
    $("#jqgWorkOrdersList").jqGrid().setGridParam({ url: urlString }).trigger("reloadGrid");
});
```

Comment: Just to update in case anyone else looks, val() doesn't work for checkboxes.  You need to use .attr("checked").

Comment: You are right, updated my answer, however I think `.is(":checked")` is more suitable here